# How to display picked image in a circle avatar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I have the following code which launches the image picker to select image from gallery.

```
File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }
```

After the image is selected, I want that image to be displayed in an already present `CircleAvatar`.
The above method getImage() is called as shown below:

```
                InkWell(
                        onTap: getImage,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          radius: 40.0,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 38.0,
                            child: ClipOval(
                              child: Image.asset('images/newimage.png'),
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
```

I have a `ClipOval` which is the child of the `CircleAvatar` and has a default AssetImage as its child . I am not able to figure out how to replace this **placeholder image** with the one that is picked from the gallery! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about `backgroundImage`? In `CircleAvatar()`, There's this property called `backgroundImage` which has type `ImageProvider<Object>?`. How do I put my picked image there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `_image` variable to check if it is null or not and then accordingly set the image in `ClipOval`.

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: getImage,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    radius: 40.0,
    child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 38.0,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: (_image != null)
        ? Image.file(_image)
        : Image.asset('images/newimage.png'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use `CircleAvatar` and provide the file object. `.image` will give you the ImageProvider that is needed.

```
CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        radius: radius,
        child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: radius - 5,
            backgroundImage: Image.file(
              profileImage,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ).image,
        ),
)
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer!!!!!. Should be the marked solution.

Comment: Worked for me! Agree, this is the best answer

Comment: This is absolutely insane. Congratulations My man!

Answer (score 3):

You can you  use CircleAvatar widget like this

```
 CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: Image.file(
               File(_image.path
                   .toString()),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,).image,
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the _image in the child of ClipOval. That will work. You can also add a check for null or empty,

```
            InkWell(
                    onTap: getImage,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      radius: 40.0,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 38.0,
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: Image.file(_image),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

it is so easy.only put your file into `FileImage` and embedded in `backgroundImage` in the CircleAvatar widget.

```
CircleAvatar(radius: 50.0,
             backgroundColor: Colors.white,
             backgroundImage: FileImage(profileImageFile))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container (
child:image != null? Container (. 
height:,
width:,
Decoration: BoxDecoratiob(
shape: BoxShape.circular
Image : DecorationImage(
Image : FileImage(image)
fit:BoxFit.fill
))
): Container (
Child:...

 ) 

 )
```

Answer (score 0):

> If one's want to store the image in backgorundImage properties of circleAvtar then the code below is bestOne:

`child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: img != null ? Image.file(img!).image :Image.asset('assets/images/startup.jpg').image,radius:70`)

Comment: This is the best one

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClipPath widget to achieve it easily

```
ClipPath(
          clipper: const ShapeBorderClipper(shape:  CircleBorder()),
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: (_image != null) ? Image.file(_image)
        : Image.asset('images/newimage.png'),)
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Use background image**

```
CircleAvatar(
                           
backgroundImage:Image.file(_image),
    ),
```

Comment: Argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to  parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.